# onBeforeUnload creates prompt even when function returns nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a page on my site to enter some values. These can be saved and modified later. I want a prompt to appear when the user attempts to leave the page, but only when there is unsaved data. I have the code to determine if a value is saved or not working fine. In the function I assign to `window.onBeforeUnload`, it should either return a string if there is an unsaved value, or nothing if nothing was entered/everything is saved. However in Firefox and Internet Explore, the prompt warning about unsaved changed appears even the function returns nothing (which will be undefined). Chrome works fine.

I have tried to instead attach the event to the window via `addEventListener` and the same result occured. I have also removed the `evt.preventDefault()` and `evt.stopPropagation()` and it still appears. I have tried setting the `evt.returnValue` to null and `delete evt['returnValue']` and it still appears.

The code is like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.onbeforeunload = this.warnUnsaved;
}

warnUnsavedRecords = (evt) => {
    if (evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();
       evt.stopPropagation();
    }

    if (this._unsaved) {
       return "There are unsaved records.";
    }
    return;
}
```

Even adding `console.log` proves it is reaching the `return` and yet it still occurs.

Comment: Normally, removing the `evt.preventDefault();` part should be sufficient. This works for me in FF at least.

Comment: @Jb31 thank you, it appears that all it took. You should post it as an actual answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, removing the `evt.preventDefault();` part should be sufficient. This works for me in FF at least.